# threading error in python

Tags: python

Probably I am overlooking something very basic.
I have a function

```
def execution(command):
    os.system(command)
```

And another function

```
def start_this_thread():
    server_thread = threading.Thread(target=execution, args=(exec_str))
    server_thread.start()
```

I get an error:

```
self.run()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 483, in run
    self.__target(*self.__args, **self.__kwargs)
TypeError: execution() takes exactly 1 argument (233 given)
```

Aparently the string length (command) is of length 233??

Answer (score 2):

Ok.. I figured it out..

Instead of

```
  server_thread = threading.Thread(target=execution, args=(exec_str))
```

it should be

```
 server_thread = threading.Thread(target=execution, args=(exec_str,))
```

Though Would love to know why?

Comment: Because when you want to define tuple with only 1 argument you need to write (blabla, ) not (blabla). And when you run `threading.Thread(target=execution, args=(exec_str))` and, for instance, `exec_str` == '123' args will equal to `['1', '2', '3']` not `['123']`

Answer (score 1):

`args` is interpreted simply as a sequence of arguments. You passed in `(args_str)`, which is a string (since the pair of brackets is interpreted simply as grouping, not as a tuple constructor). So, the string is expanded as a sequence into 233 separate arguments (one for each character in the string).

Use `(args_str,)` instead (note trailing comma) to create a one-element tuple.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that args gets expanded, which afaik means that exec_string is going from 1 item into 233.  Try putting a comma after exec_string to make it a literal tuple instead of parentheses.  I'm on mobile right now but will edit tomorrow sometime for formatting and clarity.

In python, (something)==something, but (something,) is a tuple of 1 item with something as the only element.